# Extending Firebug (Firebug/FBL is undefined)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, xul

- Firefox 3.6.8
- Firebug 1.5.4

I'm trying to write a Firefox extension that uses Firebug.  I've gotten up and running with the Firefox extension part but I just can't seem to access Firebug.  I've followed various tutorials and dug into the code of other Firebug extensions (such as FirePHP).  From what I can tell, this should work (at it's simplest):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://implementor/skin/overlay.css" type="text/css"?>

<overlay id="implementor-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script>
    FBL.ns(function() { with (FBL) {

    HelloWorldPanel = function() {}

    HelloWorldPanel.prototype = extend(Firebug.Panel,
    {
        name: "HelloWorld",
        title: "Hello World!",

        initialize: function() {
          Firebug.Panel.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        },
    });

    Firebug.registerPanel(HelloWorldPanel);

    }});
</script>


</overlay>
```

FBL is always coming back as undefined.   If I call "Firebug.Console.log(whatever)", Firebug will also be undefined.  If I call it later on (let's say, after a menu item is hit) it will work.  It's definitely a loading issue but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask on the Firebug newsgroup. http://groups.google.com/group/firebug
I guess you are not overlaying successfully, try adding window.alert(window.location.toString()) to your JS before FBL.ns

Comment: Thanks John.  Are you the man behind FireDiff?  I decided to use the source to get an idea of why mine wasn't working and I recognized your name.  Anyway, I appreciate the help!